# using a graphical application on Ubuntu 18.04 with root rights

Tags: linux, root, application

Since I've upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 I am no-longer able to do something like:

```
sudo su -

gparted
```

because now root can't access Display:0 and I've not found a way round.

Does someone knows how to get around that problem?

With gparted it isn't that bad but I use some other programmes where it doesn't works at all, as I have not got another program for doing the same. I don't want to start all as root, because I would know how to do this.

Comment: Side note, but please consider using `sudo -i` instead of `sudo su -`. One tool can become root just fine. ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is `kdesudo`, `gsudo` (I think), and some others.

Or you can copy this to `~/bin/xsudo`

```
#!/bin/bash

inner() {
    su  - "$user" -c "xauth list" |
        grep "$(echo "$display" |
                cut -d ':' -f 2 |
                cut -d '.' -f 1 |
                sed -e s/^/:/ ) " |
        xargs -n 3 xauth add &&
        "$@"
}

if [ "$1" = "---innermode" ]
then
    shift
    user="$1"
    display="$2"
    shift 2
    inner "$@"
else
    self="$0"
    sudo "${self}" ---innermode "$USER" "$DISPLAY" "$@"
fi
```

Comment: Working but unwanted side effect: this made the `.Xauthority` file owned by root in the user home directory. Another call to `xauth list` as the user yields: `xauth:  /home/fabien/.Xauthority not writable, changes will be ignored`. And now, the subsequent `xauth list` calls just hang on my machine.

Comment: I just had a read of the code (not re-tested). Did you change the case of any of the words? (upper / lower case does matter). I can see how you would get the problem if you mess up the case.

Comment: I changed the `sudo` line with `su -c '"$0" "$@"' root -- "${self}" ---innermode "$USER" "$DISPLAY" "$@"` because I don't have nor want `sudo` installed on my machine. Do think that could be the issue? I just tried it, and it does it again with just this line changed.

Comment: I was thinking, this may be an environment problem, so I added `-l` option to `su` and got: 
`xauth:  file /root/.Xauthority does not exist /
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: %s / 
xterm: DISPLAY is not set`. And the second time, same error, without the first line saying `.Xauthority` is missing. At least, in the previous version, the graphical application was working. :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pkexec` to run a GUI application as root.

```
$ pkexec gparted
```

Or:

```
$ pkexec bash
# gparted
```

`pkexec` uses PolicyKit for authorization, so you might need to get a PolicyKit in place to allow your user to run commands using `pkexec`. See [the man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/0.105/pkexec.1.html) for more details on authorization.

Comment: pkexec gparted  isn't working like sudo su - 

The connection to  Display:0 is not working and the program stops as well.

Comment: @AndreasBartels Try `sudo -H`? [This thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2393514) suggests it might work in some cases...

Comment: problem still with sudo -H gparted there and I tried other programs - Problem still existing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged into a X session as a regular user who has sudo rights, then simply opening a terminal and using `sudo gparted` will work just fine.

The `su` command behaves differently, and while it does allow you to become another user or run a specific command as another user, it does prevent connecting to your X server.

Comment: I was telling in the first step, that for gparted it isn't that important, as there is a way round but I've got other programs that has the same problem and that are not running this way round.

Comment: @AndreasBartels - this method Just Works for me for anything I've tried - `zenmap`, `gparted` (off live cd), etc.  Can you give some example apps that don't work using this method?

Comment: every Version 16.4, 12.4, 10.4 has worked this properly. now it's a bad thing, as I don't want to start as root at all. sudo gparted isn't working as this was something I tried first. Same fault. I wouln't come up with such a question if the basic function would work. But I found gparted not more usable. Some how I know that I did need it sometimes when there was a special situation with disks, as the program disks isn't doing all what you want, how you want.

Comment: @AndreasBartels `sudo su -` followed by `gparted` isn't the same as `sudo gparted` - have you actually tried my suggestion?

Comment: I had before asking tried sudo gparted, sudo su , and than inline, sudo su - and than inline and sudo -H gparted. Aktually I get it working only if I log out and log in with GNOME and Xorg but this is only a way round as I found out, that I am not more able to remote a Server because I can't connect to the Display with x11vnc so even after reading the authority out of ps aux . Looks like a problem of gdm3